# Initialization and Assignment of static Variable

Tags: c, static, initialization, variable-declaration, static-initialization

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int i=10;
  static int x=i;
  if (x == i)
    printf("Equal");
  else if(x > i)
    printf("Greater");
  else
    printf("Lesser");
  return 0;
}
```

Why this piece of code give compile time error, can someone explain what is happening behind the scene?

Comment: If you have an error message, you must always provide it in Stackoverflow questions. What is the error message? Provide the exact wording, preferably via cut & paste.

Answer (score 3):

As it is written in the C Standard

> All objects with static storage duration shall be initialized (set to
>   their initial values) before program startup

and (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 4 All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
>   or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
>   literals

That is initializers shall be compile-time constant expressions. However in the declaration

```
static int x=i;
```

there is used a run-time expression as an initialzier.

Comment: consider the following segment.
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(int x)
{
    x=x+1;
}

int main()
{
int i=10;
static int x;

x=fun(2);
printf("%d",x);
if(x==i)
printf("Equal");
else if(x>i)
printf("Greater");
else
printf("Lesser");
return 0;
}

Why it prints greater?

Comment: @SanjayVerma *Compiler warning: 'fun' must return a value*.